# Access parameters like a bash script

Tags: javascript, function, unix, signature

I want to access my routine parameters like in a bash script, by using the dollar prefix and the parameter number ($1 = first parameter, $2 = second parameter), my function signature must be empty.

```
function foo (/* Empty */) {
    return $1 + $2 + $3;
}

foo(2, 2, 4); // => 8
```

How can i do this? I tried using the apply method without success.

```
foo.apply(null, { $1: 2, $2: 2, $3: 4 });
```

Comment: You shouldn't do this.

Comment: You can try a `with` block, but I would avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please do not use this in production code:

```js
Object.defineProperties(window, {
  '$1': { get: function fn() { return fn.caller.arguments[0]; } },
  '$2': { get: function fn() { return fn.caller.arguments[1]; } },
  '$3': { get: function fn() { return fn.caller.arguments[2]; } },
  '$4': { get: function fn() { return fn.caller.arguments[3]; } },
  '$5': { get: function fn() { return fn.caller.arguments[4]; } }
});

var a = function() {
  console.log($1, $2, $3, $4, $5);
};

a("Hello", "I can't beleave", "this", "actually", "works!");
```

Wont work with `"use strict"` though.

Answer (score 0):

All javascript functions have a hidden `arguments` parameter.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments

```
function foo() {
  for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    this['$'+(i+1)] = arguments[i]
  }
  console.log($1, $2);
}
foo(1, 'b');
```

Comment: I want to a access the arguments like in a bash script. Not using the arguments object.

Comment: @user123123123 You can't.

Comment: You are not being clear.  What should $1 be?  The first parameter passed to the function?  Or do you want it to be a parameter from the command line when running the script.  Assuming you are using node.js to run it.

Comment: can't do it.  use arguments[0] for $1  or you can write a mapping function to make it args['$1] but I don't think variables can start with a $ in javascript.

Comment: "I don't think variables can start with a $ in javascript" - jQuery uses $ variable by default (`var $ = function(...) {...}`) - I'm sure that variables can start with $

Comment: good point... I've updated my example.  It works but there might be side effects when working with nested functions in this way.

Comment: Think about it this is really just a generalized solution from @PawełZmarzły since this === window in browsers.

Comment: @up, I've just changed display name from Paweł Zmarzły to pzmarzly to simplify mentioning me in comments

Comment: By convention, the dollar sign ($) is permitted to be used anywhere in a JavaScript identifier (Source: Ecma Script documentation (7.6 Identifiers, ECMA-262, 3rd Ed.)

Answer (score 0):

Well, converting parameters into bash-like variables is not that simple and requires using objects ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/use-dynamic-variable-names-in-javascript)) - either using global `window` object - then parameters are visible outside the function, or using local object to store parameters - then it's not 100% bash-like.

Code - using `window`:

```
function a() {
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    window['$' + (i + 1)] = arguments[i];
  }
  console.log($1); // 12
}

a(12, 34, "a");
console.log($1); // 12 - visible outside function
console.log($2); // 34
console.log($3); // "a"
```

Code - using object:

```
function a() {
  var vars = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    vars['$' + (i + 1)] = arguments[i];
  }
  console.log(vars.$1); // 12
  return vars;
}

var b = a(12, 34, "a");
console.log(b.$1); // 12
console.log(b.$2); // 34
console.log(b.$3); // "a"
```

Comment: That is so ... But it may be the only solution.

Comment: Yeah this is pretty clever with the window object.